# How to manually select index when querying from view

Tags: sql, sql-server

The view I need to query, which is already widely used in production and discouraged to change, is defined as

```
CREATE VIEW v AS  
SELECT ... FROM table A 
-- The view has no index,
--The table A has clustered index on col1, 
--non-clustered index id=2 on col1 include col2, col3, 
--non-clustered index id=3 on (col2,col1) include col4
INNER JOIN ........
```

My query is

```
SELECT a.something, b.something FROM v a 
--I choose something from b, so not possible to change INNER JOIN to EXISTS
INNER JOIN OtherTable b ON a.col2=b.col2
WHERE v.col1 IN (SELECT value FROM somewhere)
```

It might be that due to JOIN condition, the optimizer chooses index id=3 when querying and causes whole table selection. but when hard-coding WHERE condition, it correctly chooses index id=2 and made expected number of actual scans:

```
WHERE v.col1 IN('a','b',...)
```

However since I'm querying a view, it looks not possible to mandatory choose a specific table index.

I know the circumvent solutions to handle the problem like by quitting using the view or using `UNION ALL`, but I'm curious to whether there is a solution directly apply to the view, since the view is very complex, as well as the relationship of my selection columns.

Comment: @jarlh:Thanks for pointer ,i  just tested and forcing index hint doesn't work with views

Comment: If you're having performance issues, make sure the statistics is up to date!

Comment: @jarlh looks its not stat problem. the query runs at the time very close to an update; however from processing time, looks it never chooses the right index; and even I run the hard-coded `WHERE` condition then run the actual one right away, they still chooses different index.

Answer (score 0):

Whether SQL Server performs a table scan or a non-clustered index RID depends on a number of rows that match a 'WHERE' condition. You should not tell SQL Server query optimizer what to do, because... it knows better. Probably in your case a table scan is faster than RID lookup. Please do some [reading](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/) on the tipping point.